# How to get values from mongodb and display in HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

I am new to mongodb, I am using **Express**, **Body-Parser** and **Mongoose** and I have a mongodb database (its online, its call mlab) where i pull data from. Every thing is working fine, i have used postman to Get, Post and Delete. I am trying to get the data in JavaScript so i can display in the html. I am using Ajax, it works and returns success, but fires the fail function of the Ajax.

```
exports.photoalbum_all = function (req, res, next) {
    PhotoAlbum.find(({}), function (err, photoalbum) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send("../Views/images", {photo: photoalbum});
  });
};
```

**The mongodb model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema, 
let PhotoAlbumSchema = new Schema({
title: String,
albums:[
         {
             u_name: String,
             u_title: String
         }]
},{
  timestamps: true
});

PhotoAlbumSchema.virtual('pictureId').get(function(){
  return this._id;
});
```

**The mongodb route**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
 //
// Require the controllers
const photoalbum_controller = 
require('../controllers/photoalbum.controller');
// 
router.get('/find', photoalbum_controller.photoalbum_all);
```

**The app.js**

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const photoalbum = require('./routes/photoalbum.route'); // Imports routes for the photos
//
const app = express();
//
// Set up mongoose connection
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let dev_db_url = 'mongodb://Trex_son:Salvat1on1987@ds243254.mlab.com:43254/photoalbumdb';
let mongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_URI || dev_db_url;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use('/photoalbums', photoalbum);
let port = 1234;
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log('Server is up and running on port number ' + port);
});
```

I'm not sure Ajax is the best way to retrieve this data, is there any better to retrieve this values to the html

Comment: since everything works fine from server side, post your front end code.

Comment: what error is it throwing?

Comment: @Max, it finally worked, it was a CORS issue with chrome and when it was a success when i used datatype: jsonp with Ajax, it would fire the fail function instead.

Comment: @AntihypeBird it is working now, it was an issue with CORS on chrome, the error was a success but Ajax fires the fail function. Question is it, is ok to use Ajax with mongodb or there is a better way to pull data to HTML.